# If row empty, echo default text, else echo display data

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display "Not Provided" if addition_1 is empty in the database and if it is not empty in the database I would like to display the data?  I've tried several combination and can't see to figure out what I am missing.

```
<?php
if (empty($row[addition_1])) {
    echo "Not Provided";
} 
else {
    echo $row[addition_1];
}
?>
```

Comment: Debug by adding `print_r($row);die;` in your loop to get some insight.

Answer (score 2):

try adding quotes to your array key, like change:

```
$row[addition_1]
```

to

```
$row['addition_1']
```

Comment: I just tried that and no luck. `<?php
 if (empty($row['addition_1']))
 {
  echo "Not Provided";
 } 
 else
 {
  echo $row['addition_1'];
 }
?>`

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to add this to your SQL with `COALESCE` instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(addition_1, 'Not Provided')...
```

Just another option.  This does assume addition_1 is NULL in the db...

In case it's blank and not NULL, then try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(addition_1,''), 'Not Provided')...
```

Good luck.

Comment: haha, yeah, I saw the post updated message right after I clicked "add comment". :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm always using combination:

```
if (isset($row['addition_1']) && trim($row['addition_1']))
```

Remember, that you cannot according to documentation use any function in empty() function, that is why I'm using this. If you are 100% sure that addition_1 is always isset, you can skip that.